# Write an SQL query search

Tags: sql, oracle, search

I need to write a sql query that will find users that have at least 2 different books from set of (book1, book2 and book3) . what technique can be used to write such a query?

I want to find all users who own at least 2 books from a specified set of books ('book_1','book_2','book_3') but do not own any of the books in a second specified set ('book_4')?

[image: Example]

**EDIT:**

OP couldn't explain what he is actually looking for. What OP actually trying to do is:

Find all users who own at least 2 different books and **exclude** those users who has a book called 'book_4'.

Comment: group by & count with distinct

Comment: Can u see the picture?

Comment: Yes.Can u see the ans?

Comment: @noors the reason you get downvotes is because your question description conflicts with your comments which are conflicting one another. In one comment you say that users 1, 2, 4 should be returned. In another, you say 2 and 4. In yet another comment, you say 1 and 2. No clear description of the problem does not help anyone.

Comment: I'll make a lucky guess. Do you want to find all users who own at least 2 books from a specified set of books `('book_1','book_2','book_3')` but do not own any of the books in a second specified set `('book_4')`? If yes, edit the question and add this description.

Comment: I want to find users which have atleast 2 different books  or more,from list of books(that is book1,book2 and book3). user1 has all 4 books, so the query shouldn't return him,user2 has book1 and book3 - 2 differnet type from (1,2 or 3),what we need and query must return him

Comment: Sorry but that does not answer my question. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I am very sorry that I could not explain well. I am from another planet so my English is poor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Users,Count(DISTINCT Books) as CountOfBooks
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Users
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Books) >= 2
```

**Explanation:**

Here, we are grouping the table contents with users field and counting the number of distinct books that each user has. The `HAVING` clause is helpful to filter the result with the count of distinct book.

You can change the number 2 with the count you need. And `=` can be used for exact match instead of atleast.

See an example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8db260/6).

**EDIT:**

For excluding users with book_4, try this:

```
SELECT Users,Count(DISTINCT Books) as CountOfBooks
FROM TableName
WHERE Users NOT IN (SELECT Users FROM TableName WHERE Books = 'book_4')
GROUP BY Users
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Books) >= 2
```

**OR** a faster version (without using `IN`):

```
SELECT T1.Users,Count(DISTINCT T1.Books) as CountOfBooks
FROM TableName T1 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Users 
 FROM TableName 
 WHERE Books = 'Book4') T2 ON T2.Users=T1.Users
WHERE T2.Users IS NULL
GROUP BY T1.Users
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T1.Books)>=2
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0897e/1).

Comment: count = 2 should be changed, user have asked for at least 2.

Comment: you should not give answers to this kind of questions clearly he doestn give any effort solving it.

Comment: This query gives number of different books,what I need plus to this some definite books( 1,2 or 3 and not4)

Comment: @noors: See the edit in my answer. It will get you what you want.

Comment: Raging Bull,your edited query gives users 1,2 and 4. But it should be just 1 and 2. please help

Comment: @noors: I think, now I understand your requirement. Please see the query in **edit**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
select USERS,count(distinct BOOKS) from myTable
where BOOKS in('Book1','Book2','Book3')
group by USERS
having count(distinct BOOKS) >=2
```

Comment: Upvoted as the code does exactly what the question was asking

Comment: Sorry but your query gives users users 1,2 and 4. But user4 shouldn't be

Comment: sorry user_1 shouldn't be because he has all 4 different books(not 1,2 or 3 as needed)